# Integrating data from a hive subquery1 into the other subquery in hive

Tags: hive, subquery

I have a Hive table "tab" that the following 2 fields:"timewindow product_id_scanned"

I need a query to list the results like:"product_id %count_seen_in_window"

At the face of it, the query would look like:
"select id, count(distinct timewindow)/tot from tab group by id"

Now the tot comes from the query which represents the list of time intervals:
"select distinct timewindow from tab tot"

How do I get my result in one query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a little bit of a workaround of certain Hive limitations, but hopefully it helps:

```
SELECT
  product_id_scanned, COUNT(DISTINCT timewindow)/tot
FROM (
    SELECT
      tab.product_id_scanned AS product_id_scanned,
      tab.timewindow AS timewindow,
      tot.tot AS tot
    FROM
      tab, (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT timewindow) AS tot FROM tab) tot
  ) tot_added
GROUP BY product_id_scanned, tot;
```

Although not particularly elegant, the approach here is to create an intermediary table that has the `tot` value appended to every row as an extra column.

Comment: It works correctly. I was trying to figure out if "tot" can be used somehow as a scalar value.  From your approach, I learned it can treated as a vector with the same scalar values.

Comment: @AnantRaman I'm glad it helped - please accept my answer (the check mark symbol) if you found it useful.  As a note, there may still be opportunities for optimization here (now that I'm looking it with fresh eyes a day later) - the first thing that comes to mind is avoiding the use of a Cartesian product to append the `tot` vector.

Comment: I missed the "tick".  When I ran the hive query on a 1 node pseudo cluster, it took about 100 secs (kind of expected). My next step is run the query on impala, followed by Map Reduce Program.I will let you know how it turns out.